# Can I cast "Find Gate" when delayed in Other World?

Tags: arkham-horror

**In Arkham Horror, while delayed, can I cast "Find Gate" in Other World?**

The spell 'Find Gate', reads:

> **Movement:** Cast and exhaust to immediately return to Arkham from an Other World.

Can I, for example, cast this immediately after being drawn through a gate during the Arkham Encounters phase? This would effectively skip the Other World Encounter that is about to happen this turn, in addition to the one that would happen next turn.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the full text of the spell into your question. I know it might make it look a little more silly, but I think it makes things clearer too.

Comment: These edits substantially changed the question that was being asked. Yes, I did pose two questions, but the more specific one, that is now the only one that remains, was more of an example question to show where the other, more broad question, would apply. In fact, an answer to the broad question would have also answered the specific one. Now, the two answers here didn't address the broad question, and that might be because I poorly worded the original post, but I'm not really a fan of the edits that have been made. I believe the broad question is of more use, even if it is unanswered here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spells (and other items) will usually have some casting phase or timing defined on the card that states when they're allowed to be used.

http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Find_Gate

*Find Gate* has **Movement:** on it, so you can only cast *Find Gate* during the Movement phase. So if you were drawn through a gate due to an Arkham Encounter that said some thing like 'A Gate and a Monster appear!' you wouldn't have the opportunity to cast *Find Gate* before your first Other World encounter. But you would be able to cast it the turn after that.

This has been resolved as per the [FAQ](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/FAQs/Complete_Arkham_FAQ.pdf) page 7 under spells:

```
Q: Can a delayed investigator in an Other World cast Find Gate?

A: No the only things a player whose investigator is
delayed in an Other World may do during his Movement
Phase is stand his investigator marker up and/or trade with
another investigator in the same Other World area.
```

*This answer previously held links to places where the rules around the Find Gate spells was discussed. Since the final ruling from Fantasy Flight Games i have removed this information and the links.*

Comment: I didn't see anything about that in the rules. I would have expected it to be in the 'Casting Spells' section where spell casting is explained. Is this ever explicitly stated in the rules?

Comment: Hmmm, that's a good observation! Right now, the closest thing I can find is this from the FAQ:
Q: When can a character perform actions during a phase? 
For example, if a player with the ally Duke (“discard to 
immediately restore your Sanity to its maximum”) draws 
an encounter and has to roll a die and lose that much 
Sanity, when can he discard Duke to restore Sanity: not at 
all once the encounter card is drawn, before the roll, or 
after the roll? 
A: Actions can be performed at any time during their 
listed phase as long as any given conditions are met.

Comment: Being delayed means you loose your movement phase, as is. You may not generate movement points and subsequently use them. You can not - without further interpretation - do anything but standing your investigator up and trade with another investigator, that is in your exact location.

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast it during your movement phase. Which is over when you enter the gate.